# Google Workspaces logs to BigQuery do not have sender information

Tags: google-bigquery, google-workspace, google-admin-sdk

I set up exporting Google Workspace logs to BigQuery following instructions from [here](https://support.google.com/a/topic/9079469?hl=en&ref_topic=4490889&sjid=181099983065080406-AP). I see the logs coming in to the "activity" and "usage" tables and I am able to query them via BigQuery. However, I see that the Gmail logs in the "activity" table do not have the "message_info.source" block that contains sender information per https://support.google.com/a/answer/12384955?hl=en&ref_topic=9079469&sjid=11337154956395449958-AP. Wondering if someone else has encountered this issue.

I am fairly confident that this isn't related but I have enabled the "Allow export of sensitive content from DLP rule logs" and I still do not see the sender info in the logs

Thanks